# Trying to start ANTLR gives "NoClassDefFoundError"?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I just downloaded ANTLR, and when I try to start it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/Tool
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.Tool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I tried running it by:

```
java -cp "~/Downloads/antlr-4.5-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.Tool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ does not work in class paths.